# Get just a variable name in each iteration using an apply

Tags: r, loops, apply, var, lapply

I'm using `lapply()` with a function but, instead of get an only one name of a variable in each iteration, I'm getting every variable names from my data set.

```
colnames(data) <- c("var1", "var2")

varnames <- function(var, name){
   return(name)
}

print(lapply(data, varnames, name=names(data)))
```

I get this output:

```
$var1
[1] "var1" "var2"

$var2
[1] "var1" "var2"
```

But, I'd like to get:

```
$var1
[1] "var1"

$var2
[1] "var2"
```

Comment: You have a 2 column dataset, when you do `lapply`, it is looping through the columns i.e. a list of vectors.  You are getting every variable names, before you specified in that way `name = names(data)`.

Comment: @akrun I see... but how can I get just a variable name instead of every variable names? Name of the first variable the first time, the second one after...

Comment: Would `as.list(colnames(data))` do what you want?

Comment: You can use `lapply` on `names(data)` and use function such as `function(x) { print(x); print(dt[[x]]) }` to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you specify here in code is:

```
lapply(data, varnames, name=names(data))
```

loop over the columns of `data`, and provides an additional variable `name` to the function `varnames`. Note that here the code does not iterate over `name`, but passes it as is.

If you want to get the output you require, you can use `mapply`. This is essentially a version of `lapply` which allows multiple variables to be iterated over:

```
mapply(varnames, data, names(data)) 
  var1   var2 
"var1" "var2"
```

---

To do some operations to each of the columns, and still keep the name in some way, I would use `dplyr` (as you are not entirely clear what your end goal is, I'm guessing this is what your where after):

```
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(var1 = runif(10), var2 = runif(10), 
                  var3 = runif(10), var4 = runif(10))
data %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, median), var1:var4)
  var1_mean var2_mean var3_mean var4_mean   var1_sd   var2_sd  var3_sd
1 0.6063735 0.5308427 0.2872901 0.6043027 0.2586042 0.2303065 0.245709
    var4_sd var1_median var2_median var3_median var4_median
1 0.2721362   0.6814136   0.4535982    0.200493    0.644607
```

alternatively using `gather` from `tidyr`:

```
data %>% 
   gather(variable, value) %>% 
   group_by(variable) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, median), value)
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

  variable      mean        sd    median
    (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1     var1 0.6063735 0.2586042 0.6814136
2     var2 0.5308427 0.2303065 0.4535982
3     var3 0.2872901 0.2457090 0.2004930
4     var4 0.6043027 0.2721362 0.6446070
```

Comment: I have a dataframe with 40 variables and I want to use a function which draw a barplot for each variable. I'd like to use the name of each variable as title of each barplot. That's my goal.